# How to combine 2 SQL statements into a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine that I have a table with info regarding a person (1 line per person) lets call it `TableA`, now i want to for example to get all the persons that have debts in `TableB` and also Credit to pay Monthly in `TableC`.

Now having this done by 2 commands is easy, a simple:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableA 
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                FROM TABLEB 
               WHERE Header1=false);

SELECT * 
  FROM TableA 
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                FROM TABLEC 
               WHERE Header2=false);
```

But i don't want to make 2 separate commands to return 2 separate datatables, isn't it possible to join them together instead and get it all merged down without duplicates? Something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableA 
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                FROM TABLEB 
               WHERE Header1=false 
                 AND 
              SELECT ID 
                FROM TABLEC 
               WHERE Header2=false);
```

If this is possible, what would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `UNION`?

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id from tableB...
   UNION ALL <---note this
   SELECT id from tableC...
)
```

Comment: Hello, i dont think union all is the answear as i will get duplicate results from what i understand. example Returned Results = 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3. Is simply UNION an alternative to prevent that from happening?

Comment: well, `union` by itself would discard any duplicate values, but `in(...)` doesn't test for multiple equalities in the list. if ANY of the values in the `in(...)` list match, then the join is considered a success. having two `2` ids in the list won't make two different joins. `in(...)` is just a nice compact way of writing `where field=val1 or field=val2 or field=val3 etc...`